# Different meaning in the mysql code?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from dosyabegeni where veri_id='" . get_custom_field('dwcode') . "'");
```

### Not Working

*It says the number and the screen, **but** the application does not work*

```
 veri_id='" . get_custom_field('dwcode') . "'");

 veri_id='" . echo get_custom_field('dwcode') . "'");
```

### Working

```
 veri_id='HelloTest'");

 veri_id='1234567890'");

 veri_id='" . $_GET['test'] . "'");
```

#### Main Codes

```
 <?php
 include('/home/emre2010/public_html/EntegreOz/DosyaBegeni/config.php');
 $result=mysql_query("select * from dosyabegeni where veri_id='" .get_custom_field('dwcode') . "'");

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {

 $sira_id=$row['sira_id'];
 $veri_id=$row['veri_id'];
 $begeni=$row['begeni'];

 ?>
        <div class="reviewbox"> 
        <div class="summarywrap">  
        <div class="summarywrapinner">                       
        <div class="summary">
            <div class="reviewsection"><div class="rating points">
            <a href="#" class="begeni" id="<?php echo $sira_id; ?>">
            <span style="color:#fff;" align="center"> <?php echo $begeni; ?> </span> 
            </a>
            <p class="ratingtext">completed!</p></div>
            </div><div class="clear"></div>                
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="ratingsummary"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

What's the problem?

Comment: What does `get_custom_field()` output? That is likely your problem.  Echo out the query as sent and run it directly on the database.

Comment: What is output for: `echo "select * from dosyabegeni where veri_id='" .get_custom_field('dwcode') . "'";`

Comment: `get_custom_field()` = download code.. -- html codes are deleted and print: 78d2ef2262db9efe20ddabbc98bd0f49.. [click here for screenshot](http://imgwheel.com/medium/Phc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you meaning to run the review box from within the while loop?  If your SQL is only supposed to return one row, you really shouldn't have all that stuff within the while loop.  I don't see an end bracket.  If you are then you're doing it pretty archaically. You should put the information from the while loop into an array instead and then run a separate loop in your content, but that's not really going to solve the problem.  The only issue you could have is either not returning rows because they don't exist, or an error in your SQL.

If your SQL query isn't returning any rows then you need to do two things.  One, echo out the sql query.  And two, print any possible errors.

```
echo $sql.'<br />';
print(mysql_error());
```

You never know, you might have misspelled a column on the table of the db itself.

If that's not working, then print the $row out.

Outside of your while loop do:

```
print_r($row);
```